# Angle between two 3D vectors is not what I expected.

Tags: geometry

Using the definition of the dot product, you can find the angle between two vectors. I am experiencing an unexpected result, so my question is where did I go wrong.

I have two unit vectors in 3 dimensions. So the angle between these vectors would be just the inverse cosine of the dot product. I picked two unit vectors I know would be $45$ degrees from each other, dotted them, and took the inverse cosine.

$$\arccos\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt3}{3}, \frac{\sqrt3}{3}, \frac{\sqrt3}{3}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\frac{\sqrt2}{2},0\right)\right)$$

Look here on [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acos%28%28sqr%283%29/3,%20sqr%283%29/3,%20sqr%283%29/3%29%20dot%20%28sqr%282%29/2,sqr%282%29/2,0%29%29).

But it does not come out to be $45$ degrees, or $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ radians. It comes out to be $.61$ which is not $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$. $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is $.78$.

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why did you think these vectors are 45 degrees from each other?

Comment: Well shouldn't they be? They are in a certain plane together in the  +++ octant. One is pointing equally in the x,y and the other is pointing equally in the x,y,z. I imagine this to be 45 degrees from each other.

Comment: @DanWebster: Dan; are you sure about the vectors? Didn't you miss any certain coefficients?

Comment: This just shows the dangers of relying on imagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Calculate

$\displaystyle \cos \theta = \frac{a . b}{|a||b|}.$

What do you get?

$\displaystyle a . b = \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}}{3 \times 2}\right) + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}}{3 \times 2}\right) + (0) = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{3} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

$\displaystyle |a| .|b| = \left|~\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)^2 }~\right|. \left|~\sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 +0^2}~\right| = |1|.|1| = 1$

This comes out to: $\displaystyle \cos^{-1} \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$

Comment: How? both their magnitudes are one. The bottom of the right side becomes 1. You would get inverse cosine of square root 2/3 like wolframalpha shows.

Comment: @DanWebster: see it now or need more details? The numerator is the dot product, while the denominator is the product of their magnitudes and those are different.

Comment: I found the same result as above @DanWebster.

Comment: You're right but I don't understand how this is 35 degrees and not 45 degrees. When the components are equal in XYZ, I thought it's suppose to be 45 degrees from any of the planes (like the X Y plane)

Comment: @DanWebster: Maple admits what Amzoti found. If there are undesirable things, so we are missing additional information about the two vectors. +1

Comment: Oh well, that question will be encountered by the OP, I am sure ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Oops, I meant, I should have posed a question, find a general solution for getting an angle of 45 degrees between two 3D vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to check with Wolfram Alpha, you can ask your question somewhat more directly:

[`angle between (sqr(3)/3, sqr(3)/3, sqr(3)/3) and (sqr(2)/2,sqr(2)/2,0)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=angle%20between%20%28sqr%283%29/3,%20sqr%283%29/3,%20sqr%283%29/3%29%20and%20%20%28sqr%282%29/2,sqr%282%29/2,0%29)

You'll see that the answer is $\arccos(\sqrt(2/3))\approx0.61$, which is exactly what you got.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is backwards. Instead of this:

**Q1** The angle between my two vectors is $45^{\circ}$! Why is the dot product wrong?

it should be:

**Q2** The dot product says the angle between my two vectors is not $45^{\circ}$! Why isn't it?

And the answer is: Draw some more pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Project the problem onto the $x=y$ plane and you will see that the new coordinates are

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt6}{3}, \frac{\sqrt3}{3}\right)$$

and

$$\left(1,0\right).$$

From this, you should be able to clearly see that the angle between them is not $45^{\circ}$.