# The angle between two unit vectors is not what I expected

Tags: geometry

Ok imagine a vector with only X and Z components that make a 45 degree angle with the positive X axis. It's a unit vector. Now also imagine a unit vector that has the same direction as the positive x axis. Now imagine rotating both of these around the Z axis.

I expect the angle between these vectors to still be 45 degrees. But it's not. If you don't believe me look here. [Angle between two 3D vectors is not what I expected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360998/angle-between-two-3d-vectors-is-not-what-i-expected)

Another way to think about it is to draw a 45 degree angle between two lines on a piece of paper. Now stand the paper up, and rotate the paper. The angle between the lines are still 45 degrees.

Why is my way of thinking wrong?

Comment: @Gerry Related not duplicated, I also linked it in the post so that was quite unnecessary of you.

Comment: Dan, maybe so, but it seems to me that your question here is answered there. In any event, if the answer at the other question left you still unceertain about the facts of the matter, maybe instead of accepting an answer you ought to have expressed your uncertainty there.

Comment: @Gerry The difference between the questions is that one was proof oriented and this question is directed to conceptual understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with the vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(1/\sqrt{2},0,1/\sqrt{2})$, and rotate both by $45^\circ$ about the $z\text{-axis}$, then you end up with $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2},0)$ and $(1/2,1/2,1/\sqrt{2})$.  The second point is not $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$ as you imagined.  If you think about it, the $z\text{-coordinate}$ cannot be changed by this rotation.  If the $z\text{-axis}$ is vertical, and the $x\text{-}y$ plane is horizontal, then the height of the point above the plane is not changed by rotation about the $z\text{-axis}$.  The height remains $1/\sqrt{2}$, and the length of the horizontal coordinate remains $1/\sqrt{2}$ as well.  That would not be the case if the final vector were what you thought it was.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. I think the root of my confusion was that I thought if all the components are equal then when you measure the angle between that vector and a vector in one of the planes formed by 2 of the axes, it had to be 45 degrees. But in 3 dimensions, it turns out to be 35 degrees. As you add dimensions it decreases I think, which I still think is strange but I understand it better now.

Comment: Yes, in fact the angle goes to zero as the number of dimensions goes to infinity.  This reminds me of some similar counterintuitive aspects of high dimensions.  Imagine a $2\times2$ square subdivided into four $1\times1$ squares.  Place a circle of diameter 1 in each small square.  Draw the circle centered at the center of the $2\times2$ square and tangent to the other four.  It has diameter $\sqrt{2}-1\approx0.414.$  Now increase the dimension of the construction.  In 3-D, you have a $2\times2\times2$ cube subdivided into eight $1\times1\times1$ cubes, each containing a sphere$\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ of diameter 1.  The center sphere tangent to the other eight has diameter $\sqrt{3}-1\approx0.732.$  By the time you get to dimension nine, the center sphere has diameter 2, that is, it touches the sides of the enclosing $2\times2\times\ldots\times2$ box.  Beyond dimension nine, the center sphere extends beyond the walls of the box, and as the dimension goes to infinity, so does the diameter of the center sphere.

Answer (score 0):

The angle remains the same.

Let $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(1, 0, 1)^T$, $x_2 = (1,0,0)^T$.

$\arccos (x_1^T x_2) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Now let $Q_\theta = \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$. This represents a rotation of $\theta$ around the $z$ axis.

Note that $Q_\theta^T Q_\theta = I$. Then $\arccos ((Q_\theta x_1)^T x_2) = \arccos (x_1^T Q_\theta^T Q_\theta x_2) = \arccos (x_1^T x_2) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.